# Fetching only the not null values in a row in hive

Tags: hiveql

I want to fetch all the non nullable columns in a row, based on my key in hive.

My intermediate output is something like this:

```
ID  COL_1  COL_2  COL_3
1    A     NULL      C
2   NULL    B      NULL
3   NULL    D       E
```

Actually I want my final output to be like:

```
ID  COL (new column based on the value of COL_1,COL_2,COL_3)
 1   A
 1   C
 2   B
 3   D
 3   E
```

Basically, it is a kind of transpose, but I want to know whether this can be achieved in hive. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
SELECT NVL(COL_1, NVL(COL_2, NVL(COL_3, null))) AS COL
    FROM Your_source_table;
```

There might be some other more efficient ways. But this works for me.